# How to render dynamic translations in NuxtI18n?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n, vuex4, nuxtjs3

I want to render list based on translations of 2 languages , one list for Arabic and one for English how can I do it?

```
<i18n lang="json5">
en:{

},
ar:{
}
</i18n>
```

I want to use these lists eg

```
  englishNameList: [
      { name: '', id: 1 },
      { name: '', id: 2 },
      { name: '', id: 3 },
      { name: '', id: 4 },
      { name: '', id: 5 },
    ],

  arabicNameList: [
      { name: '', id: 1 },
      { name: '', id: 2 },
      { name: '', id: 3 },
      { name: '', id: 4 },
      { name: '', id: 5 },
    ],
```

I want to add these list into i18n json5 so It could be rendered into v-autocomplete

```
 <v-autocomplete
            ref="selectedJob"
            v-model="selectedJob"
            :rules="[requiredRule]"
            :dense="$vuetify.breakpoint.mobile"
            outlined
            color="black"
            :items="englishNameList"
            item-text="name"
            item-value="id"
           
          >
      
          </v-autocomplete>
```

I want pass data to :items based on translations from i18n json5?
How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your usage if you want to use i18n inside html you have to use {{ $t(the variable of string or simply 'translate able string') }} .
Otherwise if u wanna use it on JS side of the component you have to use this.$t(the variable of string or simply 'translate able string').
I assume that from your data the Name key inside your arrays are translate able, you don`t need to create 2 separate list for each one. Just introduce the names in en and ar. Then use $t to change between locales.

Comment: I just need to add seprate list for Each translation, I am using NuxtJS and using Componenet based translation.

I am confused with creating list, and adding it v-autocomplete